# Spacing within Equation Containing Commands

Tags: spacing, equations

I'm using random numbers to generate relatively simple equations for students to solve.

> Example:
>   -5n - 3 = 7

But when I use random numbers and/or commands inside of equations, I get undesired spacing. It's still usable, but does not look nice.

What's the easiest way to fix this?

I guess that the problem has something to do with putting commands inside of the equation, but I'm not sure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgffor}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{   \pgfmathrandominteger{\A}{2}{10}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\B}{-10}{10}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\B}{\B}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AbsoluteB}{\ifnum\B<0{int(-1*\B)}\fi}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\Answer}{0}{11}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A*\Answer + \B)}
    }

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\huge

BAD SPACING ON LEFT SIDE
\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{\B}\else{+\B}\fi = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{\B}\else{+\B}\fi = \C$

\vskip 1cm

DESIRED SPACING ON LEFT SIDE

$2x-5=13$

$7x+8=36$

\vskip 1cm

FAILED ATTEMPT TO FIX SPACING

\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{-\AbsoluteB}\else{+\B}\fi = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{-\AbsoluteB}\else{+\B}\fi = \C$

\end{document}
```

[image: Various Spacings]

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Don't use so many braces. Try `$\A x \ifnum\B<0 \B \else +\B \fi = \C$`.

Comment: Specifically, putting braces around `{+B}` changes its spacing to `mathord`. Within the braces, you get `\mathbin` spacing between `+` and `B`, but the space to the left is set to the same spacing in the middle of `AB`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is `{+\B}` and using `\B` for negative values instead of the binary `-` operator.  The braces around `+B` change its spacing as if you’d written `\mathord{+\B}`.

Within the atom, `-B` is typeset like `-2`, with `-` as a unary operator and the same spacing on either side as `B` would have.  That is, on the right, it happens by chance to be correct, but on the left, you get the same spacing between `A` and `{-B}` that you would between `A` and `B`.

Bernard has already posted a working solution, but I thought it could be supplemented with some explanation of why this happened.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take into account that `+` or `–`  are *binary`symbols, that require something on either side, so you just have to add an empty`{}` on the left side to solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgffor}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{ \pgfmathrandominteger{\A}{2}{10}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\B}{-10}{10}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\B}{\B}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AbsoluteB}{\ifnum\B<0{int(-1*\B)}\fi}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\Answer}{0}{11}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A*\Answer + \B)}
    }

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\huge

BAD SPACING ON LEFT SIDE
\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{\B}\else{+\B}\fi = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{\B}\else{+\B}\fi = \C$

\vskip 1cm

DESIRED SPACING ON LEFT SIDE

$2x-5=13$

$7x+8=36$

\vskip 1cm

SUCCESSFUL ATTEMPT TO FIX SPACING

\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{{}-\AbsoluteB}\else{{}+\B}\fi = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \ifnum\B<0{{}-\AbsoluteB}\else{{}+\B}\fi = \C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of TeX conditionals *doesn't* require braces around the true and false branches. To be more precise, adding braces can do harm!

What harm? Well, `$1{+2}$` is not the same as `$1+2$`, because in the former `{+2}` is treated as a single unit and the sign is considered unary, hence attached to the digit, because it's preceded by nothing in the subformula.

You want to print `\B` as is if it is negative, because it's already equipped with its sign and output a `+` if it is positive.

I'll add how to not print it if it zero, but you can decide yourself.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}{%
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\A}{2}{10}%
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\B}{-10}{10}%
  \signedvar{\B}{\B}%
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\Answer}{0}{11}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A*\Answer + \B)}%
}
\newcommand{\signedvar}[2]{%
  \edef#1{%
    \ifnum#1=0 \else
      \ifnum#1<0 \else +\fi #1%
    \fi
  }%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\InitVariables

$\A x \B = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \B = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \B = \C$

\InitVariables

$\A x \B = \C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\signedvar` has two arguments in case you want to keep the “unsigned” value in your text.